# SQL Query: Get Latest N days of datetime values in Timezone

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have a table `Events`

```
name     VARCHAR(255)
dt_start DATETIME (stored in UTC)
dt_end   DATETIME (stored in UTC)
```

I need to query `Events` in the table for the latest `N` days based on `dt_start` and a Timezone conversion.  There can be multiple `Events` per day.  I.e., **Give me the latest 10 days of events in Timezone: America/New_York without respect to today().**

I'm looking for the query to return the latest records no matter how far in the past or future they are but based on the number of days the `Events` `dt_start` span.

I could get the result with two queries, the first to find the maximum `dt_start` in the given Timezone.  Then, subtract N days from that value and execute a second query to get all the events with `dt_start` greater than or equal to the value.  Or, potentially, use sub-queries to achieve the same result.  I'm looking for a slick way to do it with a single, fast query.

Comment: Time zones is something that is very messy, and I would try to search for some library that can help you with that.

Comment: I can pass datetime parameters to the query in UTC, that's no problem.  Timezones can get confusing but if you set some solid conventions for your application up front, it makes it much easier.  I only store UTC in my database and convert wherever else necessary.

Comment: Perhaps:  `ORDER BY dt_start DESC LIMIT 10`?